# Is the field of constructible numbers $C$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

say that $C$ is the field of constructible numbers.
I want to know if C is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or not. My first answer would be no :
If C is a finite extension, with $[C : \mathbb{Q}] = n$, then it is generated by an element $\alpha$ where its minimal polynomial $P$ has degree $n$.

We can take a constructible number $\lambda$ whose minimal polynomial has degree $ > n$ (because the constructible numbers are a subfield of the field of algebraic numbers), then $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(Q(X))$ is not isomorphic to $C$, and it seems that this field is larger that $C$, although all its elements are constructible numbers.

Am I wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: If $a>0$ is constructible then so is $\sqrt a$. Hence all $\sqrt[2^k]2$ are in $C$. Note that $[\Bbb Q[\sqrt[2^k]2]:\Bbb Q]=2^k$